# Show filterable rows count

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ),
    size VARCHAR ( 50 ),
)

CREATE TABLE country (
    country_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ),
    product_id INT
)

CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ),
    product_id INT
)
```

I want my query to return the list of product in this way.

- Query result needs to have to objects: `meta` and `result`
- The `result` needs to be paginated with 10 objects. And `meta` should include the total count of filtered products, count of attributes of products.
- When country is filtered, I want to see other country choices' names and counts as well, not only the country filtered (same for the color).
- If the color is filtered, I don't want to see the countries that are not available with this color for the products we have (and vice versa):

```json
{
    "meta": { 
        "count" : 200,
        "next_page": true,
        "colors": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "red", "count": 5}, 
            {"id": 2, "name": "white", "count": 10}
        ],
        "countries": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Germany", "count": 120},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Albania", "count": 201}
        ],
        "sizes": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Big", "count": 45},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Small", "count": 63}
        ]
    },
    "result": [
        {
            "product_name" : "Milk",
            "color": "White",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "product_name" : "Milk2",
            "color": "White",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "product_name" : "Milk3",
            "color": "White",
            "country": "Germany"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I've done:

```
WITH results as (
    SELECT 
        product.id,
        product.name,
        product.size,
        color.name,
        country.name
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN color ON color.product_id = product.id
    LEFT JOIN country ON country.product_id = product.id
    WHERE color.name = ANY('{White}')
)
SELECT
(
    SELECT 
    jsonb_build_object(
        'count', count.full_count,
        'next_page', count.full_count - (1 * 10) > 0
    )
    FROM (SELECT count(id) AS full_count FROM results) AS count
) AS meta,
(
    SELECT jsonb_agg(result_rows)
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM results
        LIMIT 10
        OFFSET (1-1) * 10) AS result_rows
) AS result
```

I've tried lot's of thing and did not get the result of getting name and counts of country and colors. So I didn't include that part of query. BTW, the the slight change in query returning result is acceptable.

Any help is highly appreciated. I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL. You can see this type of query used in Ebay (search results page) where page filter properties change while you select different filters to correspond the available choices and counts depending your current filters.

Comment: your data model is strange : having the column 'product_id' in table 'country' is strange, because it means that you have a different 'country_id' for each 'product_id', even if the country 'name' is the same. For example, having two products in Germany will lead to two different 'country_id' for that country... ? Same comment on table 'color'. With this data model, you can't get the desired result with the number of products = 120 for country_name = Germany and country_id = 1.

Comment: Could you update the results with descriptions of what they *mean*?  For example, if you're filtering to white, how can `count=200`, but `white_count=10`?  Please give example data that should generate the results you're looking for *(changing the expected results to smaller counts to make the example data manageable)*, and include for each element of the result an explanation of how you arrived at that figure?  `Note`: For optimal performance this should likely be dynamic SQL, where your app/ORM writes different *(but similar)* SQL statements for different filters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your data model looks like strange (or wrong). I would suggest you the following data model instead, so that you can store several products with the same size and/or the same color and/or the same country. The only limitation here is that one product may only have one size, one color, and one country. You will have to create new tables if you want to manage one to many relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE size (
    size_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 )
) ;

CREATE TABLE country (
    country_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 )
) ;

CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 )
) ;

CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ),
    size_id INT CONSTRAINT rf_size REFERENCES size (size_id) MATCH SIMPLE,
    color_id INT CONSTRAINT rf_color REFERENCES color (color_id) MATCH SIMPLE,
    country_id INT CONSTRAINT rf_country REFERENCES country (country_id) MATCH SIMPLE
) ;
```

Then you can get your expected with the following query :

```
WITH global_list AS (
SELECT p.size_id, p.color_id, p.country_id
     , s.name AS size_name, clr.name AS color_name, cty.name AS country_name
     , count(*) AS product_count
  FROM product AS p
 INNER JOIN country AS cty
    ON cty.country_id = p.country_id
 INNER JOIN color AS clr
    ON clr.color_id = p.color_id
 INNER JOIN size AS s
    ON s.size_id = p.size_id
 GROUP BY p.size_id, size_name, p.color_id, color_name, p.country_id, country_name
), result_list AS (
SELECT jsonb_build_object('product_name',p.name,'color',clr.name,'country',cty.name, 'size', s.name) AS result
     , count(*) OVER () AS total_count
  FROM product AS p
 INNER JOIN country AS cty
    ON cty.country_id = p.country_id
 INNER JOIN color AS clr
    ON clr.color_id = p.color_id
 INNER JOIN size AS s
    ON s.size_id = p.size_id
 WHERE cty.name = COALESCE('Albania', cty.name)  -- enter here the country filter criteria if any, like 'Germany', or NULL if no country criteria
   AND clr.name = COALESCE(NULL, clr.name)       -- enter here the color filter criteria if any, like 'White', or NULL if no color criteria
   AND s.name = COALESCE(NULL, s.name)       -- enter here the size filter criteria if any, like 'Medium', or NULL if no size criteria
), country_list AS (
SELECT jsonb_build_object('id', gl.country_id, 'name', gl.country_name, 'count', sum(gl.product_count)) AS country
  FROM global_list AS gl
 WHERE gl.color_name = COALESCE(NULL, gl.color_name)  -- same color criteria than above
   AND gl.size_name = COALESCE(NULL, gl.size_name)    -- same size criteria than above
 GROUP BY gl.country_id, gl.country_name
), color_list AS (
SELECT jsonb_build_object('id', gl.color_id, 'name', gl.color_name, 'count', sum(gl.product_count)) AS color
  FROM global_list AS gl
 WHERE gl.country_name = COALESCE('Albania', gl.country_name)  -- same country criteria than above
   AND gl.size_name = COALESCE(NULL, gl.size_name)    -- same size criteria than above
 GROUP BY gl.color_id, gl.color_name
), size_list AS (
SELECT jsonb_build_object('id', gl.size_id, 'name', gl.size_name, 'count', sum(gl.product_count)) AS size
  FROM global_list AS gl
 WHERE gl.country_name = COALESCE('Albania', gl.country_name)  -- same country criteria than above
   AND gl.color_name = COALESCE(NULL, gl.color_name)  -- same color criteria than above
 GROUP BY gl.size_id, gl.size_name
)
SELECT (SELECT jsonb_build_object('result', jsonb_agg(result)) FROM result_list LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0)
    || jsonb_build_object('meta'
                         , jsonb_build_object( 'count', (SELECT total_count FROM result_list LIMIT 1)
                                             , 'next_page', (SELECT total_count > 10 FROM result_list LIMIT 1)
                                             , 'countries', (SELECT jsonb_agg(country) FROM country_list)
                                             , 'colors', (SELECT jsonb_agg(color) FROM color_list)
                                             , 'sizes', (SELECT jsonb_agg(size) FROM size_list)
                                             )
                         )
```

ps : the first query `Global_list` could be implemented as a `view`

The result looks like :

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 2,
    "sizes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Small",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Medium",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    "colors": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "White",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Blue",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Germany",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Albania",
        "count": 2
      }
    ],
    "next_page": false
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "size": "Medium",
      "color": "White",
      "country": "Albania",
      "product_name": "Milk2"
    },
    {
      "size": "Small",
      "color": "Blue",
      "country": "Albania",
      "product_name": "Milk3"
    }
  ]
}
```

All details in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wGLTn0WQ)

Comment: That model does not map well to products that are available in different colours ; it would require repeated product rows. That would need some "link tables" allowing one product to associate to many countries, many colours etc. Additionally, some characteristics would warrant being kept product specific; while you wouldn't need a new USA instance for each product, you may want a separate RED instance for each product, as that would allow easy renaming of one product's RED to, for example, CarnivalRed. So, while I hold with your premise, I feel it is too simplistic.

Comment: Also, while your WHERE clauses are "neat", it does obfuscate use of indexes and can lead to significant performance penalties.

Comment: @MatBailie : your first comment just repeat what I says in my introduction, ie one-to-many relationships are not supported in this proposal. However there is no input data in Ulvi's question that refers to this kind of requirement. Regarding your second comment, I just disagree wih you : all the CTE can rely on indexes, even though this question is not part of the initial question, so it is out of my current consideration here.

Comment: `WHERE Y = COALESCE(X, Y)` is objectively *not* SARGable.

Comment: @MatBailie : sorry `WHERE Y = COALESCE(X, Y)` is _objectively_ _SARGable_ with PostGres when X is a constant. IF X is NULL then the WHERE clause is true obviously so that the query relies on an Seq scan on the full table which is normal. WHEN X is not NULL, then the query can rely on an index scan, see the demo at `https://dbfiddle.uk/XNsGUiXm`

Comment: Now try that with a parameterised query, instead of using literals.